# Error 619 when copying value from SAP GUI screen

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I made a macro to open the `mmbe` transaction and copy and paste it into a cell. The problem is that when copying the error appears:

> 619

Can someone help me?

```
Sub teste()
   Set session = GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine.Children(0).Children(0)

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "mmbe"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtMS_MATNR-LOW").Text = "33.000000"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtMS_CHARG-LOW").Text = "33.006011"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtMS_CHARG-LOW").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtMS_CHARG-LOW").caretPosition = 9
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCC_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]/shellcont/shell/shell_item[1]").Copy
  
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02") 

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

```
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCC_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]/shellcont/shell/shell_item[1]").Copy
```

the error is only on the line above

expected the macro to return the information in an excel cell